# Java Mail TIF attachment extraction

Tags: java, email

I'm trying to get the attachments of a POP mailbox with java mail. It has several attachments along with a TIF image file. I iterate through the Multipart:

```
for (int j = 0; j < multiPart.getCount(); j++) {
        BodyPart bodyPart = mp.getBodyPart(j);
        Object bodyPartContent = bodyPart.getContent();
...

}
```

But when it comes to the TIF image attachment, the bodyPart.getContent() returns null. The TIF image is not damaged nor wrong format, I tried with several images, and I'm using the latest javax.mail 1.4.7.
Any ideas, what the problem could be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution: the TIF image attachment is not stored in the bodyPartContent, but in an InputStream in the bodyPart, so it can be accessed through 
    bodyPart.getInputStream();